# ReloadRowsAtIndexPaths with no Row Animation animates

Tags: uitableview, swift2, xcode7

The problem with this code (inside **func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)**)

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

if indexPath.row > 1{
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
}
if tDate[activeRow].count == 0{
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

is that both **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** are animated, although **withRowAnimation: .None** is specified. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is often the case in `iOS` and `OS X` that you end up with an implicit animation for one reason or another (for example, the code is being executed by other code that has already triggered animation).

It can be especially difficult to control animations with `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` in my experience.  Your best bet is probably to put the calls to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` into a closure passed to `UIView`'s `performWithoutAnimations:` method:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    if indexPath.row > 1{
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }
    if tDate[activeRow].count == 0{
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }
}
```

Note: It's also not a bad idea to call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` before and after multiple updates that happen all at once.

Comment: But tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() did the trick! Even without UIView.performWithoutAnimation. Thank You!

Comment: `performWithoutAnimations` did the trick for me. No `beginUpdates` or `endUpdates` calls were needed.

Answer (score 20):

While an appropriate solution for this problem was described by Charles, it did not answer the question as to why `UITableViewRowAnimation.none` provides an animation.

According to the docs for `UITableViewRowAnimation.none`, "The inserted or deleted rows use the default animations." Therefore, while `.none` sounds like there shouldn't be an animation, it actually acts more like `.automatic`.

[image]

I would have left this as a comment, but comments cannot contain pictures. Please note that this answer is not meant to solve the problem as Charles has already done that. This is strictly for reference for the next person wondering why `UITableViewRowAnimation.none` provides an animation.